# Feature engineering - filter out columns based on linear correlation result

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

Besides the other factors (such as domain knowledge), is there any rule of thumb or best practices to keep/remove features that were identified with high correlation between each other?

The problem is, there could be a circular in correlated features, such as A correlates with B and B correlates with C. In this case, is it better to remove A and C and keep B?

Here is an example list of features with Pearson correlation score > 0.85:

```
# Distinct column pairs with correlation >= 0.85:
('area_mean', 'radius_mean'): 0.99
('area_se', 'perimeter_se'): 0.94
('compactness_worst', 'compactness_mean'): 0.87
('concave points_worst', 'concave points_mean'): 0.91
('concave points_worst', 'concavity_worst'): 0.86
('concavity_mean', 'compactness_mean'): 0.88
('concavity_mean', 'concave points_mean'): 0.92
('concavity_mean', 'concave points_worst'): 0.86
('concavity_mean', 'concavity_worst'): 0.88
('concavity_worst', 'compactness_worst'): 0.89
('perimeter_mean', 'area_mean'): 0.99
('perimeter_mean', 'concave points_mean'): 0.85
('perimeter_mean', 'radius_mean'): 1.0
('radius_se', 'area_se'): 0.95
('radius_se', 'perimeter_se'): 0.97
('texture_worst', 'texture_mean'): 0.91
```

In this case, what is the "formula" to list out the columns to be filtered out?